# Opensearch Alerting: Per Document Monitor to include few document field(s) in alert message

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am newbie to Opensearch / Elasticsearch. Apologies in advance in case wrong terminologies are used. We recently started to use OpenSearch as logging database.

We are trying to setup `Alerting` in Opensearch. There are 4 options available for alerting - `Per query monitor`, `Per bucket monitor`,
`Per cluster metrics monitor` & `Per document monitor`. As we are using Opensearch for storing application logs, therefore we more interested to go ahead with `Per document monitor` in order to apply more complex query based on business needs.

We have configured `Per document monitor` with below extraction query snippet -

```
{
    "description": "",
    "queries": [
        {
            "id": "log-level",
            "name": "log-level",
            "query": "status:\"error\"",
            "tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Its working well. Now the requirement is to pipe `app_log.message` in alerts message (to slack) -

```
"_source": {
   "app_log": {
       "message": "[No Bank Account id found with XX-YY-ZZ]",
       "caller": "/app/internal/usecase/implementation/xyz.go:1801",
       "level": "error"
   },
   "status": "error"
}
```

We already tried with couple of blogs available on internet -

1. https://forum.opensearch.org/t/how-do-i-include-message-fields-in-the-alert-action-message-for-per-document-monitor/14428
2. https://forum.opensearch.org/t/how-do-i-include-message-fields-in-the-alert-action-message/8167/12

Apart from that, there is one more issue want to highlight is `Per document monitor` does work with nested fields (**"query": "app_log.level:\"error\""**) -

```
{
    "description": "",
    "queries": [
        {
            "id": "log-level-error",
            "name": "log-level-error",
            "query": "app_log.level:\"error\"",
            "tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if more information is required.